# SharePoint2010 Feature activation does not act the same if manually or powershell script

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-2010

I have a SharePoint solution, containing 3 Features. One feature is Site scoped, and two are Web scoped.

The site feature contains different lists, 2 workflows and content types. Two of them are quasi similar, one is called `CTTaskAchat`, and the other one is called `CTTaskAccord`
The two web features contains lists definitions, lists instance and event Receiver.

When i deploy the solution with my powershell script and that I **enable the feature with the powershell script**, almost everything works pretty fine. The problem is that i can't find my content type `CTTaskAccord` nowhere. And I don't understand why i can't find it whereas i can find the `CTTaskAchat` content type.

If i deploy the solution with my powershell script, but that I **activate the feature manually** (i.e. through the Site Settings menu) the content type does appear.

So if you have any idea of where I could find my solution.

For your information, I would love to delete all the site collection and create a new one, but it's an update of the solution, so it's not possible.

EDIT : I've just noticed that some other points of the feature don't get activate (i have a list which doesn't exists with powershell but exists when i activate the feature manually)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You able to find the content type inside : Site Actions -> Galleries -> Site Content Types.

when you activated the site feature just check the feature is activated properly.

Comment: Hi, 
well actually that's the problem, when i go into site action feature administration, my feature is activated, but when i go into the site actions -> Galleries --> site content types, i can't find the CT. Whereas if i deactivate and reactivate the feature manually i will find it there

Comment: Then, you can try using STSADM command line tool to add wsp and deploy in it.

Comment: else deactivate the solution, retract and then again to try using PS. may you get any luck.

Comment: Amen, 
Using stsadm works. 
Can you explain what's the difference between stsadm -o activatefeature and Enable-SPFeature ?
Thanks

Comment: Actually, when you deploy your solution using visual studio, SharePoint itself run stsadm command to activate the feature.

Comment: dont forgot the tick the answer, if you fell this is right answer